# Finding the width of \bf text for sizing a paragraph in a table

Tags: tables, fonts, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have this structure, which builds a table exactly the width of the text, split into two columns. I want the left column to be exactly the width of the longest words in the column, but to still be a paragraph (instead of aligning l).

I'm using `\widthof{Longest Text in Column}}` at the moment, but that breaks when I want to use bold font.

Example of what's working and broken:

```
\documentclass[final,openbib,oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    {\Large This Page Works:}\\\\
    \hspace*{-6pt}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth+12pt}{p{\widthof{Army Group Centre}}|X}
        Army \hfill Group \hfill North \par 
        \vspace{\baselineskip} 
        More text and stuff will go in the paragraph, that's why it's a
        paragraph instead of ``l''
        & \lipsum[2]\\
        Army Group Centre & \lipsum[2]\\
        Army \hfill Group \hfill South & \lipsum[2]\\
    \end{tabularx}
    {\Large This Page Does Not:}\vspace{.5\baselineskip}\\
    %% trying to measure bold font causes error:
    %
    % \hspace*{-6pt}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth+12pt}{p{\widthof{\textbf{Army Group Centre}}}|X}
    %
    %% measuring without bold font causes linewrap:
    \hspace*{-6pt}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth+12pt}{p{\widthof{Army Group Centre}}|X}
        \textbf{Army \hfill Group \hfill North} \par 
        \vspace{\baselineskip} 
        More text and stuff will go in the paragraph, that's why it's a
        paragraph instead of ``l''
        & \lipsum[2]\\
        \textbf{Army Group Centre} & \lipsum[2]\\
        \textbf{Army \hfill Group \hfill South} & \lipsum[2]
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `\\newlength{\WidestLength}` and then store the length as:

```
\settowidth{\WidestLength}{\bfseries Army Group Center}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- There is no need to guess the `\hspace*{-6pt}` and `+12pt`. You can simply remove the column padding that gets added at the start and end of the table via `@{}`.
- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[final,openbib,oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\WidestLength}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    {\Large\noindent This Page Works:}
    
    \settowidth{\WidestLength}{Army Group Center}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\WidestLength}|X@{}}
        Army \hfill Group \hfill North \par 
        \vspace{\baselineskip} 
        More text and stuff will go in the paragraph, that's why it's a
        paragraph instead of ``l''
        & \lipsum[2]\\
        Army Group Centre & \lipsum[2]\\
        Army \hfill Group \hfill South & \lipsum[2]\\
    \end{tabularx}
    
    {\Large\noindent This Page Now Also Works:}
    
    %% trying to measure bold font causes error:
    %
    % \hspace*{-6pt}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth+12pt}{p{\widthof{\textbf{Army Group Centre}}}|X}
    %
    %% measuring without bold font causes linewrap:
    \settowidth{\WidestLength}{\bfseries Army Group Center}
    \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\WidestLength}|X@{}}
        \textbf{Army \hfill Group \hfill North} \par 
        \vspace{\baselineskip} 
        More text and stuff will go in the paragraph, that's why it's a
        paragraph instead of ``l''
        & \lipsum[4]\\
        \textbf{Army Group Centre} & \lipsum[4]\\
        \textbf{Army  Group \hfill South} & \lipsum[4]
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\settowidth{\WidestLength}{\bfseries Army Group Center}`

Comment: @egreg: Is that more efficient?

Comment: Yes; and moreover it doesn't even require `calc` as it is part of the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, two (three, counting removing calc?) birds with one stone and a really fast answer!